# My Samsung galaxy keeps on showing the software update & telling me to restart. Help?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung galaxy s3 kept on showing restart & the software update & I don't know what to do. Should I restart it? I'm just scared of what's going to happen next. What if it won't work, & what if it keeps on restarting by itself? I'm scared. I just got my Samsung galxy s3 last week. Will it be broken? Help!?

Comment: Why do you think the update will break it?

Comment: @DanHulme S/he mus have seen number of question in site like this saying that it broke. While rare, its possible.

Comment: @roxan Please don't speculate about the OP's situation. I don't want to reassure him or her inappropriately if it turns out there's a genuine reason to think it might break things.

Comment: @DanHulme Whatever I've said is genuine. Look at this site itself and other forums and you'll see people sometimes facing this problem.